# Getting twitter-bootstrap tooltip to work on images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get twitter-bootstrap tooltip to work on some images I have.  This is the code I have:

```
@foreach($favorite_friends as $friend)
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title data-original-title="{{$friend}}"><img id="{{$friend}}" src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{$friend}}/picture?width=200&height=200" alt="{{$friend}}" height="40" width="40" class="img-rounded"></a>
@endforeach
```

Unfortunately, when I hover over the images, there is not tooltip appearing.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), tooltips must be activated via JavaScript..

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip({});
```